# Using graph to translate differing representations

Tags: algorithm, graph, merge

I have a data translation problem, and would like guidance on how I can crack it:

I have an inbound list of items that represent train cars assigned to segments along a journey. Each item has an index, a car reference, an origin and a destination.
E.g.

```
Index Car Origin Destination
1     C1  L1     L2
2     C2  L1     L2
3     C3  L1     L2
4     C1  L2     L3
5     C2  L2     L3
6     C4  L2     L3
```

The example above show four cars (C1, C2, C3, C4). Cars C1-C2 travels from L1 to L3. C3 travels from L1 to L2. C4 travels from L2 to L3. The index maintains the order of the cars within each 'leg', but it is relative: For the second leg (L2-L3), the first index in use is 4.

I need to translate this into a different model that provides a distinct list of cars, while maintaining the order of the cars within the train.
E.g.

```
Index Car Origin Destination
1     C1  L1     L3
2     C2  L1     L3
3     C3  L1     L2
4     C4  L2     L3
```

The second model doesn't allow for a complete re-ordering of the train cars mid journey. I.e. I can't allow cars A, B, C, D to change order to A, C, B, D. I would have to apply some heuristic to obtain the resulting car order, and it would not reflect reality. I'm happy to accept this drawback.

Also, although the target model index specifies car order within the train, it doesn't matter whether I index from the front or the back of the train. It would be nice to use lower indeces for car assignments earlier in the Journey.

So, for the solution: I think I need to employ graphs to make this translation but I'm unsure where to start. I think I should be modeling a car as a vertex, and a coupling of a two cars in the same leg as an edge. But I'm not sure where I go from there.

I'd be very grateful for any pointers on how to approach the problem: Modelling tips, merging algorithms...

**Edit**
One more complication: On some legs the order of cars in a train may completely reverse. This is used to indicate the train changed direction. I don't need to capture that reversal, but I do need to retain the inter-connected order of the cars.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think it will be enough to simply loop once through the input list, keeping track of the current minimum origin and maximum destination for each car that you see (e.g. in a hashtable that has `car` as the key and a pair `minOrigin, maxDest` as value).  Then just write out the contents of this table.  Not sure where your "heuristic" would come into it, so I may have misunderstood.

Comment: I need to preserve the order of the cars as they were coupled together on each leg. Sorry if that wasn't clear. When I iterate over a Hashtable, any ordering would be lost.

Comment: In that case I think you could change the hash value from a pair to a triple, `(minIndex, minOrigin, maxDest)`, and sort by this field just before writing out.

Comment: I don't think its this simple. But I will give it a go in code to flush it out.
I've edited the question btw. There's an added complication of train reversals that I was hoping to avoid in the question, but maybe its necessary to state it

Comment: Hi j_random_hacker, I don't think sorting by minIndex will work. I could get a new car appearing on the second leg before the first car on the first leg. Using the example above, I could get: `4 C4 L2 L3, 5 C1 L2 L3, 6 C2 L2 L3` I think the solution lies in constructing a graph of interconnected cars, and then outputting a sequential view of that graph.

Comment: Do you mean that my "minIndex" idea won't work if you changed the last 3 lines of your example to be what you wrote in your comment?  (BTW, put a "@" in front of my username to notify me.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker. Yes, that's what I mean. The change means that Car C4 gets coupled to the train at Location L2, in front of C1. So from L2, the train consists of C4, C1, C2. But sorting by min index will give this order: `C1(i=1), C2(i=2), C3(i=3), C4(i=4)`

Answer (score 1):

In essence, and leaving aside the question of reversed segments, this problem reduces to a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms) for which a number of simple and efficient algorithms exist (see the Wikipedia link for examples). To construct the graph, we use the cars as vertices and insert an edge from `Ci` to `Cj` if `Ci` immediately precedes `Cj` in some leg. (This minimizes the number of edges, which reduces the cost of an `O(V+E)` topological sort.)

But that won't work with "reversed" legs; these will cause the topological sort to fail. So the other part of the problem is to detect reversed legs. Here I'm assuming that there is no definite list of reversed legs; if there were, the solution would be obvious.

I think the following will work reasonably efficiently, but it may well not be optimal.

Let's say that two legs are *forward compatible* if they share at least two cars and the order of the shared cars is identical in the two legs. Similarly, two legs are *reverse compatible* if they share at least two cars and the order of the shared cars in one is the exact reverse of the order of the shared cars in the other. Finally, two legs are *bidirectionally compatible* if they share at most one car. (It's possible that two legs don't fit into any of these three categories, in which case they are incompatible and the problem has no solution.)

It's easy to categorize the relationship between two legs. With the right datastructure (a hashtable, for example) finding the list of shared cars between two legs is `O(min(m,n))` where m and n are the sizes of the legs (in number of cars), as is checking if the shared cars appear in the same or reversed order in the two lists. So constructing the entire array of relationships between all possible pairs of legs should be `O(L·N)` where `L` is the number of legs and `N` the number of cars. (I don't have a proof of this assertion, so it could be wrong. But it seems reasonable.)

With the graph of compatibilities, we need to assign a direction to each leg. We do this using a traverse of the graph, using the following recursive procedures:

```
# Direction is either Forward or Reverse. We assume a function reverse(D) which
# returns Reverse if D is Forward, and Forward if D is Reverse
setDirection(Leg, Direction):
  + If the Direction of Leg is Direction, return.
  + If the Direction of Leg is set and not the same as Direction, fail.
  + Otherwise:
    + Set the Direction of Leg to Direction.
    + For each L such that Leg is forward compatible with L:
        + Call SetDirection(L, Direction)
    + For each L such that Leg is reverse compatible with L:
        + Call SetDirection(L, reverse(Direction))

setAllDirections():
  + while some Leg L does not have its direction set:
    + SetDirection(L, Forward)
```

Now, we can reverse the order of the cars in the legs which are marked as reversed, and apply the topological sort.

Note that it is possible for the above procedure to a consistent set of leg directions which does not correspond to "reality", because the decision to set the initial direction of a new Leg in the last line is totally arbitrary. But I think it is the best that we can do.

Comment: Hi @rici, thanks very much for your in depth description for a solution. I am going to try and use your ideas on a solution. It will no doubt take some time for me to implement (this is a background task right now until the work gets assigned). But I will get back to this thread and report on any success (or lack of) in due course.
Cheers